# using google maps to get bus stops list

Tags: c#, web-services, google-maps-api-3

Given a certain region in the united states, I'd like to get a set of bus stops in that region. I'd like to use this to catalog the bus stops in Austin, Texas. Is there a way of doing this with a web service from the google maps? I'm using c-sharp to make the web service calls.

Comment: Which webservice of google do you plan to use?

Comment: This would be a good starting point http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: What have I tried? Nothing, otherwise I would have said what I've tried. I've researched the question and I'm unsure of whether or not this is possible, ergo, I'm asking the question.

Comment: Then read this http://stackoverflow.com/faq especially the first section

Comment: Is this not a "practical, answerable problem"? Are web services that google produces that provide data for map queries not "software tools commonly used by programmers"? This is not a "chatty, open-ended question", I can't imagine "an entire book that answers my question"  about using the google maps api to get at bus stops, and I would not like "to participate in a discussion" about anything. I just want to know if there is a way to access bus stops from web services from google maps.

Comment: `We feel the best Stack Overflow questions have a bit of **source code** in them, but if your question generally covers …

a specific programming problem, 
a software algorithm, 
software tools commonly used by programmers, 
practical, answerable problems that are unique to the programming profession, 
… then you’re in the right place to ask your question!`

Comment: Great, then I'm in the right place.

Comment: I hope, you'll get great answers

Comment: I don't understand you. You don't expect good answers because I downvoted your question? (Although your question is perfect). I see upvoters to your comment. Maybe they would post good answers

Answer (score 1):

Never used it, but looks like it may be close: 
http://www.transitchicago.com/developers/bustracker.aspx

Did not find a regional one, this one just covers Chicago it looks like.